# Experience with Pololu Robots

Tags: pololu

Has anyone had much experience with the [Pololu](http://www.pololu.com/) Robots

Which are the coolest? what do you recommend i get?

I'd like to hear about some cool projects with these Robots  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3pi:
this has an awesome design and is great for programming practice.  I'd recommend it for any high school studients or uni students just getting into electronics
http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/975

Answer (score 2):

This was a really good starter kit:
Elenco 21-880 Line-Tracking Mouse 
http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/301

Answer (score 1):

Pololu now sells the [Pololu Zumo Robot for Arduino](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2506), which is a good choice if you are familiar with Arduinos or want to benefit from the large support community Arduino offers.

[image: Zumo robot without Arduino]